# Extend Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, json.net, extending

I want to extend `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` Class in order to obtain fast access (in form of properties) to some expressions made on-the-fly from JObject's contents. Let us call the extended class `JRecord`.

I also need that `JObject` instances can be easily cast to and from the extended type `JRecord`. The question is: how I take a `JObject` instance and cast it as my extended type (which also inherits from `JObject`), in a way it keeps all its content but gets "dressed" with the extra properties when narrowing from `JObject` to `JRecord` and "striped" of those properties when widening from `JRecord` back to `JObject`?

Below is my first scratch and I omitted most of the properties because its string building is complex and irrelevant to the problem, which raises on both custom `CType()` operators, where .NET tells me that

1. [Conversion operators cannot convert from a type to its base type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbb9k0c(v=vs.80).aspx)
2. [Conversion operators cannot convert from a base type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0f19hy(v=vs.90).aspx)

So, what should I do? Should I create a bare new instance and create children with the same content from those of the object I want to cast?

```
Public Class JRecord
    Inherits JObject

    Public Sub New()
        MyClass.New
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return MyBase.Value(Of Integer)("id")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property NomeSigla As String
        Get
            Return String.Format(
                "{0} ({1})", 
                MyBase.Value(Of String)("nome"), 
                MyBase.Value(Of String)("sigla"))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads Shared Narrowing Operator CType(json_object As JObject) As JRecord
        Return DirectCast(json_object, JRecord)
    End Operator

    Public Overloads Shared Widening Operator CType(json_record As JRecord) As JObject
        Return json_record
    End Operator

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use inheritance and conversion operators in this case.  Instead, I would use composition here.  In other words, make the `JRecord` class wrap the original `JObject` and delegate to it as needed.  To convert from a `JObject` to a `JRecord`, make the constructor of the `JRecord` accept a `JObject`.  To go the other way, just make a `JObject` property on `JRecord` and have it return the inner `JObject` directly.

```
Public Class JRecord

    Private innerJObject As JObject

    Public Sub New(jObject As JObject)
        innerJObject = jObject
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property JObject As JObject
        Get
            Return innerJObject
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return innerJObject.Value(Of Integer)("id")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property NomeSigla As String
        Get
            Return String.Format(
                "{0} ({1})",
                innerJObject.Value(Of String)("nome"),
                innerJObject.Value(Of String)("sigla"))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
Dim jr as JRecord = new JRecord(JObject.Parse(jsonString))
Dim id as Integer = jr.Id
Dim ns as String = jr.NomeSigla
Dim jo as JObject = jr.JObject
...
```

If you absolutely must use inheritance, because you want to pass the `JRecord` directly to other places in the application that expect only a `JObject`, you could do this:

```
Public Class JRecord
    Inherits JObject

    Public Sub New(jObject As JObject)
        MyBase.New(jObject)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property JObject As JObject
        Get
            Return Me
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer
        Get
            Return Value(Of Integer)("id")
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property NomeSigla As String
        Get
            Return String.Format(
                "{0} ({1})",
                Value(Of String)("nome"),
                Value(Of String)("sigla"))
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

This is nearly the same thing, except now the `JRecord` *is* a `JObject` so you can pass it around freely.  The tradeoff is that now it has to copy all the properties when the `JRecord` is first constructed.  We take advantage of `JObject`'s built-in copy constructor to do this.

Comment: Yes, as I continued to research, I found out this is the *proper* way to work here. But suppose I have this class that returns `JObject` in several operations and will now return `JRecord`. How could I make the new type seamlessly mimic `JObject` along the rest of the application, or this is not possible and I'm aiming for too much? (I know I'd better refactor the whole thing, and I intent to do it, but I would like to keep it running in-between, even if a little slower and heavier than before).

Comment: For the places where you need a JObject, I would just change the callers to pass `jRecord.JObject` instead of passing `jRecord`.  But if there are too many places like that to change, then you can still make an inheritance based approach work.  I've updated my answer to show how.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!